# Use SQL 'like' in Pandas with input()

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

so I'm using the code below to SELECT columns FROM a certain table in SQL Server.

```
sus_base = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT screen_name, user_id, text FROM [dbo].[TABLE_ONE]", con)
df1 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT screen_name, user_id, text FROM [dbo].[TABLE_ONE] WHERE text like '%car%'", con)
df2= pd.read_sql_query("SELECT screen_name, user_id, text FROM [dbo].[TABLE_ONE] WHERE text like '%plane%'", con)
df3= pd.read_sql_query("SELECT screen_name, user_id, text FROM [dbo].[TABLE_ONE] WHERE text like '%quality%'", con)
```

But, I have to do this matching for a lot of strings. I tried the following in Python which did not work:

```
test = pd.read_sql_query(("SELECT screen_name, user_id, text FROM [dbo].[TABLE_ONE] WHERE text like '%s%'", input()), con)
```

It gives me the following error, after asking me for input:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '("SELECT screen_name, user_id, text FROM [dbo].[TABLE_ONE] WHERE text like '%s%'", "'car'")': bytes or integer address expected instead of tuple instance.
```

And yes, I also tried it without the '' quotes around car.

df1 would then look like:

```
JAN | 20938 | Hi I am looking for a car somewhere
BOB | 38470 | Guys, where is my plane?
ELSA| 49850 | Never know what to do next..
CARL| 08923 | The quality of this product is amazing!
ETC.
```

You can imagine it would be a lot of work to create this. So it would be nice if the end-user can just type in the word he is looking for in the string of texts and it would return those texts like it would when I type them in the example above. Then I'll make sure it gets into a dataframe and/or Excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input is not being translated into text that pandas needs to send the query.  In the line:

```
pd.read_sql_query(("SELECT ... WHERE text like '%s%'", input()), con)
```

What is actually being fed is `pd.read_sql_query((str, str), con)`. In other word, you sent a 2-tuple of strings and the connection object, it expects just a string and the connection object.  Try formatting the string instead:

```
pd.read_sql_query("SELECT ... WHERE text like %{}%".format(input()), con)
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your answer. However, it asks for a column name now. When I changed it to the following below, it worked perfectly thanks!!

..query("SELECT ... WHERE text like '%{}%'.format(input()), con)

Comment: Cool, i will update my answer.  Please remember to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I marked it as answered ;). Thanks once again